# How to set a javascript variable to a list from a model in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have a rails application where in I have a `Post` Model, I am using `acts_as_taggable_on` gem for the tagging functionality. I am working on autocomplete tag suggestions, and want to set a javascript variable to the list from my `Post` Model. I am using `jquery-ui` autocomplete for autocomplete functionality.

This is my `_form.html.erb` where there is a form field that accepts the `tags` for a particular post.

```
<%= form_for Post.new do |f| %>


<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :message, "Post Your Thoughts:", class: "col-md-4 control-label message-label" %>

      <%= f.text_area :message, class: "form-control" , rows: "7" %>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags:", class: "col-md-4 control-label message-label" %>

      <%= f.text_field :tag_list, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter tags separated by Comma"  %>


  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Submit Post" , class: "btn btn-info" %>
```

```
<!-- Ajax for autocomplete -->
<script>
  $(function() {

   var availableTags = "...Here want a JSON list of the tags present in database..."

$( "#post_tag_list" ).autocomplete({
    alert("availableTags");
  source: availableTags
});
});
```

Now how can I put the list of all the tags in `var availableTags` of javascript?

**Update 1**

Now what I am doing is that I have a helper method `get_autocomplete_tag_list` 
that further calls a method of `Post` model that returns the list of `tags`.
Now as @Prakash has suggested I use

```
 var availableTags = <%= raw get_autocomplete_tag_list.to_json %>;
```

to use get the tag list from the server.

Now my question is that is there any problem with this method of getting the list of tags considering the fact that as of now I am getting trouble in working with Ajax and fetching the tag list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, i recommend to use a more clean solution. If your tags reach a few thousand entries, it's always loaded into your html result, which i find a bad solution in terms of performance and bandwidth (not using caching even if this is clearly cachable). You should load this through AJAX, or use a gem which provides exchange between Rails and JS, like Gon: https://github.com/gazay/gon

For instance, you could use Gon this way:

In your controller:

```
gon.available_tags = tags
```

In your jQuery UI script:

```
var availableTags = gon.available_tags
```

There's also a RailsCast for this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try with getting list of tags in hash as:

```
var availableTags = "<%== Hash[tags].to_json %>"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, your solution works !! But as @wiesion suggested, I am trying to add the ajax functionality to it.